# numeric parametric sweep for specific parameter

Tags: functions, function-construction, procedural-programming

Let's say I have the following set of parameters:

```
param=
{a->1,b->2,c->3}
```

and the following function that uses the parameters:

```
func = a+b*x+c*x^2
```

I can apply the parameters to the function by the following assignment:

```
func /.param
```

> 1+2*x+3*x^2

Now I would like to change only the param c for some specific param, let's say:

```
c -> {10,22,23,1}
```

**How can I create a new set of param, which should look like that in the end:**

```
param = {
{a->1,b->2,c->10},
{a->1,b->2,c->22},
{a->1,b->2,c->23},
{a->1,b->2,c->1}
}
```

**such that I can sweep through the parameters of c without having to retype every time the parameters from a and b ?**

*What I tried:*

```
param ={
a->#[[1]],b->#[[2]],c->#[[3]]} &/@ {Table[1,{i,1,4}],Table[1,{i,1,4}],{10,22,23,1}}
```

but this did not work out + it is not very nice, as the variable `i` has to be adjusted manually to the number of different `c` values there exist.

Comment: It might be more expedient to do the following instead: `func[a_, b_, c_][x_] := a + b x + c x^2; Table[func[1, 2, c][x], {c, {10, 22, 23, 1}}]`

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, this is only a toy example. My program is much longer and the parameters are evaluated at different instances.

Comment: I suggest that you go easy with rules and replacements. Try pure function.

Comment: Btw.: `func` is not a function; it is an expression.

Comment: As for adjusting `Table`, you can do `Table[...,{i, Length[cvalues]}]`, if you have your c values in a list `cvalues`.

Answer (score 1):

There's this way:

```
param = Thread[{a -> 1, b -> 2, Thread[c -> {10, 22, 23, 1}]}]
(*
  {{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 10}, {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 22},
   {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 23}, {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 1}}
*)
```

Maybe also this?:

```
func = a + b*x + c*x^2
(*  a + b x + c x^2  *)

csub = List /@ Thread[c -> {10, 22, 23, 1}]
(*  {{c -> 10}, {c -> 22}, {c -> 23}, {c -> 1}}  *)

func /. csub /. {a -> 1, b -> 2}
(*  {1 + 2 x + 10 x^2, 1 + 2 x + 22 x^2, 1 + 2 x + 23 x^2, 1 + 2 x + x^2}  *)
```

If your `func` is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), you can do this:

```
func /. c -> {10, 22, 23, 1} /. {a -> 1, b -> 2}
(*  {1 + 2 x + 10 x^2, 1 + 2 x + 22 x^2, 1 + 2 x + 23 x^2, 1 + 2 x + x^2}  *)
```